# Developing a new dexterity widget and field

Tags: plone, dexterity, z3c.form

I need to develop a dexterity content type with a particular field/widget.

This widget is like a multiselection widget but I need to give the 
possibility to upload a file for every choosen option. Something like this:

```
[]  option 1 Upload a file: [              ] [ Browse ]

[X] option 2 Upload a file: [              ] [ Browse ]

[]  option 3 Upload a file: [              ] [ Browse ]
```

Any idea/pointer on how to implement this on dexterity? I think it has to do with z3c.form mostly. Any example of similar widget/field is welcome, as any pointer to existing packages :)

I would also manage the vocabulary TTW, if possible, so users with a particular role can update the list.

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't used this myself I suspect you could look at [collective.z3cform.datagridfield](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.z3cform.datagridfield/) and the related [demo code on github](https://github.com/collective/collective.z3cform.datagridfield_demo) for pointers on how to use subforms and widget factories.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but seems overcomplicated. Maybe I should start from the multiselectwidget and try to add the needed pieces.